# Postgresql not starting on well-know port

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql9.5 on a ubuntu 16.04 server VM. My institute network has blocked the port 5432 and hence I need to use 443 instead. But when I change my postgresql.conf to use this port, the server does not start at all. What should I do to solve or diagnose?

Comment: `sudo netstat -nlp` will show you which process already listens on 443. `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log` should give more information on errors when starting. And if `postgresql` is not running with system privileges, you can only use ports > 1023 (if the default is not changed) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged.

Comment: I am using sudo to start the postgresql service, but it still doesn't start on 443 or 80. Is there any other change I need to make to run postgres as root?

Comment: As far as I know from the documentation, `postgresql` will not start when run from a privileged account (like `root`); using `sudo`to start the service does not change the behaviour, as the owner running the daemon will be switched to `postgres` (or whatever user is defined). If you really need to access your database via port 80 or 443, you might use `authbind` or port redirection via iptables, see  [Running network services as a non-root user](https://debian-administration.org/article/386/Running_network_services_as_a_non-root_user).

Comment: And look at the discussion on [Allow non-root process ...](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/linux-allowing-an-user-to-listen-to-a-port-below-1024)